# How to fix "cc: error: unrecognized command line option '-Wshorten-64-to-32'" issue on Mac

Tags: python, macos

You may have following issue while compiling python packages on Mac:

`cc -fno-strict-aliasing -fno-common -dynamic -arch x86_64 -arch i386 -g -Os -pipe -fno-common -fno-strict-aliasing -fwrapv -DENABLE_DTRACE -DMACOSX -DNDEBUG -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -Wshorten-64-to-32 -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -Os -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -DENABLE_DTRACE -arch x86_64 -arch i386 -pipe -I/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/include/python2.7 -c src/misaka.c -o build/temp.macosx-10.9-intel-2.7/src/misaka.o`

`cc: error: unrecognized command line option '-Wshorten-64-to-32'`

`error: command 'cc' failed with exit status 1`

Answer (score 9):

Solution is to run commands below:

`export CC=/usr/bin/clang`

`export CXX=/usr/bin/clang++`

Answer (score 1):

If you see this problem on a Mac OS X system, it is likely because you are running Python2.7 and using distutils.

By default, Python2.7 on Mac OS X is compiled with the **alias** "cc". At compile time, "cc" refers to "clang". Clang is the default program that Apple uses to compile C and C++ code.

**Solution 1**

The most appropriate solution is to ensure that "cc" refers to the correct compiler on your Mac OS X distribution. Try typing into the terminal:

```
ls -l `which cc`
```

If the output does not resolve to "/usr/bin/cc -> clang", or something similar that points to clang, then you should fix this by removing (or relabelling) "cc" programs in your path that do not point to clang.

If you have installed gcc or some other c/c++ compiler then it may have added a link to your path that refers "cc" to a different compiler. This is not recommended, because other compilations in the system that rely on cc referring to clang, or have used cc in the past expecting clang may fail. A prime example is what brought you to this page.

**Solution 2**

As mentioned by Igor you can type in the terminal before executing python setup code and/or compiling python code:

```
export CC=/usr/bin/clang
export CXX=/usr/bin/clang++
```

**Solution 3**

You can also set these options inside of python with:

```
import os
os.environ["CC"] = "clang"
os.environ["CXX"] = "clang++"
```